# Retrieving images from ftp via laravel with vue frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, ftp

maybe I am missing sth completely but I need to access pictures that are located on a ftp folder via laravel. The frontend is vue which calls the data over api.

This works without a problen when retrieving, editing and setting simple .xml files to the storage.

However, once I try to get an image via Storage::disk('ftp') or Storage::disk('sftp') ->get($folderpath) I just get back �� for 99%. This means the file is found but the return is screwed.

Any ideas what I am missing here? I feel like an idiot.

Comment: or is it common usage to put the image into the storage folder and access that one via storage link?

Comment: This looks like ascii/binary mode issue. Check if your Laravel FTP settings does not have `transferMode` set to "ascii/text".

Comment: Upon getting the image from my ftp, storing the image in my storage folder the image is stored and can be viewed, e.g. within phpstorm without any problems. When I try to retrieve said image from my frontend vue (two seperate systems) I still get my lovely question marks

Comment: I've understood that you use the Laravel storage API to retrieve the image for the frontend.

Comment: I wrote my answer misleading I guess. I use axios from my frontend to an api route in laravel. the controller then gets the corresponding .jpg.